# Is this a bug in .NET's Regex.Split?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two regular expressions, for use with `Regex.Split`:

```
(?<=\G[^,],[^,],)
```

and

```
(?<=\G([^,],){2})
```

When splitting the string `"A,B,C,D,E,F,G,"`, the first one results in:

```
A,B, 
C,D, 
E,F, 
G,
```

and the second results in:

```
A,B, 
A, 
C,D, 
C, 
E,F, 
E, 
G,
```

What is going on here?  I thought that `(X){2}` was always equivalent to `XX`, but I'm not sure anymore.  In my actual problem, I need to do something like quite a bit more complex, and I need to do it sixty nine times, so just repeating the pattern is less than ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx)

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

The internal parentheses are capturing.  Try using `(?:[^,],)` instead.

Comment: That or pass in `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`

Comment: Ah, that's actually a nifty feature.  Too bad it is counter intuitive and weird.

Comment: @JohnGietzen I should note that many languages share this featuer.

Comment: I rarely use Regex.Split, so this is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

You have a capture group in your second expression. Try non-capturing parens:

```
(?<=\G(?:[^,],){2})
```